# How to control column width in jira

Tags: jira

I am (unsuccessfully) trying to control the width of columns in jira. Does anyone know how to format tables so they don't look like the image below?

i am currently formatting by:

```html
||Document Library||combination of Report, white papers / articles, case study, document library, press kit, publication, report, fact sheet, campaign|| || || ||
|Field Group|Field name|Field type|Existing field|description|
| |Title|title|x| |
```

[image]

Comment: [I don't think you can](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=tables).

Answer (score 4):

This is a kludge but it works for me (Jira 7.3).

Go to **text** mode editor.

Place text like this in a squeezed cell

```
{color:#ffffff}================={color}
```

This will persist in visual edit mode. It places some white non-breaking text in the cell.  Using color:#eeeeee might be better so you can just see what's going on.

Comment: `{color:transparent}` :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit the column width in JIRA. JIRA tables are very simplistic and don't support any custom formatting. Checkout [Atlassian](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=tables) guide. It doesn't offer any formatting options for row or column width or height adjustment.